# Small adjustments in formatting to make my work fit on an integer number of pages

Tags: formatting, margins

Suppose I am doing some work which does not have very tight formatting restrictions. My work goes a little bit over 2 pages, but, if I change the margins from 1 inch to .97 inches, the work fits on 2 pages.

Is there a way to automate this process of tweaking the formatting to fit everything on a certain number of pages?

I am specifically looking for my work to look like it takes up an integer number of pages (assuming it is long enough to cover one page).

I had originally restricted my question to margins but I guess it applies to any other tweak that could be done.

Comment: Since LaTeX breaks a page right after it collects enough materials without looking further, one can construct a document that is either 8.5 pages or 9.5 pages. Is there any specific reason to fill the last page?

Comment: Except margins, there are so many ways to control the number  of pages. Some evil macros make paragraphs/pages one line shorter. Some adjust the spaces between lines/paragraphs/equations. Which one do you prefer?

Comment: I would prefer the second option.